# Filtering NA values in dplyr pipe and summerising only numeric column means

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataframe structure like below

```
$ Lead.Score                        : int  105 120 150 60 80 0 80 0 80 145        
$ Average.Time.Per.Visit            : num  0 83.8 4 0 0 ...
$ TotalVisits                       : int  0 5 2 1 2 0 2 0 2 4 ...
$ Page.Views.Per.Visit              : num  0 2.5 2 1 1 0 2 0 2 4 ...
$ Average.Time.Per.Visit.1          : num  0 83.8 4 0 0 ...
$ Last.Activity                     : chr  "Page Visited on Website" "Email     
$ Last.Activity.Date                : POSIXct, format: NA NA ...
$ First.Landing.Page.Submission.Date: POSIXct, format: NA NA ...
$ Created.On                        : POSIXct, format: "2016-07-31 17:11:00"
```

I want to calculate mean of all the numeric and int columns. How to do it in dplyr?

I did something like this

```
train_webdata %>%
    select(which(sapply(., is.numeric)))  %>%
    group_by(Lead.Stage) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean,na.rm=TRUE))
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarise_if`

```
train_webdata %>%
      group_by(Lead.Stage) %>%
      summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Using a reproducible example

```
data(iris)  
iris[1:3, 1] <- NA #create some NA elements
iris$Sepal.Length <- as.character(iris$Sepal.Length) #for testing
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>%
     summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE)    
#    Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#      <fctr>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     setosa       3.428        1.462       0.246
#2 versicolor       2.770        4.260       1.326
#3  virginica       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

---

Regarding the OP's error, the `group_by` operation is called after the `select`.  As the 'Lead.Stage' column is not showed in the OP's `str`, it is not clear whether it is a non-numeric column or not.  If it is non-numeric, it gets removed after the `select`.  So, we can do the `select` operation after the `group_by` step

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    select(which(sapply(., is.numeric))) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
#        Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#      <fctr>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     setosa       3.428        1.462       0.246
#2 versicolor       2.770        4.260       1.326
#3  virginica       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Comment: There is also a `select_if` function in dplyr now, which can be used like `select_if(is.numeric)`.